# error in installing knife-ec2 plugin

Tags: knife, chef-infra

While installing knife-ec2 plugin.I am facing the following issue:

root@ip-10-ggg-ff-abc:/opt/chef/embedded/bin# gem install knife-ec2
ERROR:  Error installing knife-ec2:
        mime-types requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is very clear...

One of the gems for `knife-ec2` requires a certain Ruby version (1.9.2 or higher). You are running a version of Ruby less than 1.9.2. Upgrade the Ruby in your omnibus package or use a Ruby version manager to install a newer Ruby.